# Как отключить компиляцию TypeScript в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, typescript

Для компиляции TypeScript в JavaScript и последующей минификации используется Gulp и мне не требуется отдельная компиляция при сборке проекта. Как отключить компиляцию при сборке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отключения компиляции *TypeScript* при сборке проекта используется параметр `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` в первой секции `<PropertyGroup>` файла проекта `.csproj`.